# Playing audio from Google App Engine development server in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, html5-audio

When playing audio from a Google App Engine development server (1.7.0) running on my local machine, audio will only play once in Chrome (20.0.1132.47). The same audio works correctly when calling play() multiple times once deployed to the production server.

In Firefox audio plays correctly using either server.

I'm using Buzz (http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/) although I get the same problem trying to use the audio API directly.

My code plays the audio every 2 seconds and looks like this:

```
var mySound = new buzz.sound( "/audio/hoversound", {
    formats: [ "ogg", "mp3", "wav" ]
});
setInterval(function() {
    mySound.play();
}, 2000);
```

My app.yaml has the following:

```
- url: /audio
  static_dir: static/audio
  mime_type: audio/ogg
```

It behaves the same with or without the mime_type.

Note that changing the URL to "http://somewebsite.appspot.com/audio/hoversound" in the Javascript code lets the sample play multiple times.

Is this a bug in Chrome, or the AppEngine dev server, or a combination of the two?

**EDIT:** This is a bug in Chrome, which doesn't support audio seeking if the server returns the file using a 200 OK response rather than 206 Partial-Content. There's an open issue here:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121765
The AppEngine development server only implements HTTP 1.0, which is why the issue shows up there.

Comment: Check out the activity in the Network tab of the developer tools (Wrench -> Tools -> Developer Tools). It would be helpful to know if the requests are not being made for some reason or if they are being made and fail somehow.

Comment: This isn't really anything to do with App Engine. Your client is playing the audio, not the server.

Comment: @AdamThomason In both situations (debug and real server) Chrome reports two network requests per audio file. The first is always shown as (pending), with a request size of 13 bytes. However the second request differs.

On the real server the request response is 206 Partial Context and the size shows as "(from content)", however on the debug server the response is 200 OK and the size shown is the actual size of the sample.

Comment: @NickJohnson The problem appears to be caused by the way the development server serves the audio data, so it is related to App Engine.

Comment: @Deltaflux The dev_appserver just serves the file as-is. It's not a problem with App Engine.

Comment: @Deltaflux I've seen the same behavior in Chrome - two requests.